# Error 90 after execution in MakeFile

Tags: makefile

I am very disappointed by the fact that this Makefile is outputting nonsense errors!

```
bin:
    mkdir -p bin
    gcc ./lsmodf/main.c ./lsmodf/oggetto.c ./lsmodf/lsmodfunctions.c -o ./bin/custom-
lsmod
clean:
    rm -rf *o bin/custom-lsmod
    rm -rf *o bin
test:
    rm -rf *o bin/custom-lsmod
    rm -rf *o bin
    mkdir -p bin
    gcc lsmodf/main.c lsmodf/oggetto.c lsmodf/lsmodfunctions.c -o bin/custom-lsmod
    @echo "\n\n\033[5;1m----------------------------------------\033[0m"
    @echo "\033[1;31m LSMOD senza opzioni \033[0m\n"
    bin/custom-lsmod 
    @echo "\033[5;1m----------------------------------------\033[0m"
    @echo "\033[1;31m LSMOD con ordinamento per id\033[0m\n"
    bin/custom-lsmod sort=id
    @rm -rf *o bin/custom-lsmod
    @rm -rf *o bin
```

Whenever I execute **`make test`** it compiles everything, runs bin/custom-lsmod and then throws:

```
make: *** [test] Error 90
```

and it stops. I mean: it doesn't execute the instructions under that line.

Comment: What is `custom-lsmod`? Does it return the value 90 to the system? Make might interpret that as failure.

Comment: Looks like `bin/custom-lsmod` returned 90, so Make stopped there.

Comment: Solved, I had forgotten to write "return 0" at the end of the .c file.

Comment: Click the checkmark button next to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those ones who received this kind of error:

> Looks like bin/custom-lsmod returned 90, so Make stopped there.

As Biffen said, it is an error returned by the executable. The compiler didn't return anything, but I forgot to put `return 0` at the end of my code, and it seems to be that the cause of problem.

Hope this could help people who encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you do not have the execution rigths.

Try adding `chmod +x bin/custom-lsmod` before `bin/custom-lsmod`.

[Thread on Error 126](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18807/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-make-error-codes)

Comment: I've never encountered a system where lack of execution permission returns 90 (126 seems more common), so I'd say that's unlikely the reason. Moreover, `chmod` in the Make target seems like a strange approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a hyphen at the beginning of the command:

```
-bin/custom-lsmod
```

This tells Make to ignore the error.